# How to dynamically specify parameters when using scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I have a complicated model function that is composed by 12 other functions. I have about 10 parameters. I use the model function both to fit data and to generate contour plots. Sometimes I am only interested in estimating only a few parameters, and fixing the rest, setting them as global variables. Other times I want to estimate most parameters, and fix only a few. Every time I change the set of which parameters to estimate and which to fit, I go through my 13 functions, changing all the calls to only include those parameters I want to estimate. Can this be done more dynamically? Perhaps also avoiding global variables?

Comment: Would you mind providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `partial` function from the `functools` library can help you ([here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) is the documentation).

For instance, one of your functions has the following form:

```py
def f(x, a, b, c, d):
    # a very complex expression
    return ...
```

where `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are the parameters to be optimized using `curve_fit` by SciPy.

Suppose that you need to optimize the parameters `a` and `b` and you want to keep `c` and `d` fixed. You can write:

```py
# constant value
c0 = ...
# constant value
d0 = ...
f_partial = partial(f, c=c0, d=d0)
```

now you get a new function with a simplified signature and you can pass `f_partial` to `curve_fit` and only `a` and `b` will be optimized.

You can now leverage the `partial` function to choose which parameters to optimize.

[This tutorial](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-partial-functions/) can also help you to understand better how the `partial` function works.